# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno' Curses Module error

Tags: python, windows, python-curses

I am getting an error about `curses.initscr`. What do I need to do?

```
import curses

screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho
curses.cbreak
screen.keyboard(True)

try:
    while True:
        char = screen.getch()
        if char == ord("a"):
            print('Forward')
finally:
    curses.nobreak()
    screen.keypad(0)
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python3\PythonWork\Test1.py", line 24, in <module>
    screen = curses.initscr()
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 30, in initscr fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

What does this mean?

I work on windows and I managed to get the `curses` module on it.